# RavenDb: Computed fields in the result of IDocumentQuery

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb4

The official RavenDB v4 [documentation suggests](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/migration/client-api/session/querying/transformers) to use `IRavenQueryable<T>.Select()` method for getting custom fields in the result set. It works well even for computed fields, e.g.

```
session.Query<Order>()
       .Select(x => new { Total = x.Lines.Sum(l => l.PricePerUnit * l.Quantity) })
```

**Question:** Is there a way to have computed fields in the result set (like above) when using `IDocumentQuery<T>` or `IAsyncDocumentQuery<T>` instance instead of `IRavenQueryable<T>`?

The [documentation says](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/querying/query-vs-document-query) that the `Query` requests get converted into `IDocumentQuery<T>` under the hood. However, the closest method for narrowing down the output field set is `SelectFields<T>()`, which doesn't have an option for having calculated fields in the result set.

P.S. The [docs say](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/querying/query-vs-document-query) that `Query` is always translated into the `DocumentQuery` object. However, I couldn't find in the [code](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb) how it's been implemented (though I guess it's done via [IQueryable.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.expression.aspx)).
Maybe [RQL](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/querying/what-is-rql) is a way to go now...

Comment: There is something called QueryData, see here:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/java/indexes/querying/projections#example-iii---projecting-arrays-and-objects

It is actually documentation for java, but c# version will look the same. 
What's wrong with using IRvaenQueryable for such casts?

Comment: @Marcin, it looks that [QueryData](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/v4.0/src/Raven.Client/Documents/Queries/QueryData.cs) is used just for mapping static fields to serve `SelectFields<T>()`. I'd prefer `IDocumentQuery<T>` mostly because it's a bit easier to aggregate some common functionality via manipulating with strings rather than lambda expressions.